# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi signal weak

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

It's been a while sine I've used Ubuntu and I've forgotten some things. I'm running a dual boot OS, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04. My WiFi connects with no no problems at all with Windows 8 but when I try and connect on Ubuntu it shows WiFi connections are available but unable to connect because the signal is too weak even though I haven't moved my WiFi adapter (you can see this in the two screen-shots). My WiFi adapter is a TP-Link TL-WN821N and any help would be appreciated but ideally any tasks will have to be done offline .

[image: Windows 8 Screenshot]
[image: Ubuntu Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem lately and find out that some wifi cards like **Realtek RTL8723BE** have some problems. In my case it was same. I got a solution for this on [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304607&page=6&p=13425505#post13425505).

**Solution :**

1. Download the driver from [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) Git repository.
2. Unzip the package and open terminal in that folder.
3. $ make
4. $ sudo make install
5. $ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
6. $ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2

**Note :**

You have to do these tasks on every kernel upgrade.

Comment: You can use dkms to make automatically every time the kernel is updated.

Comment: Please help me to do that.

Comment: Search on that question, if its not asked already then ask it and I will answer it or someone else will.

Comment: This worked like a charm :) thank you very much